# Como ejecutar store procedure con parámetros de tipo IN OUT en Oracle

Tags: oracle-11g

Tengo este store procedure creado:

```
CREATE or replace  PROCEDURE PAZKO.SplitAprobadores (InputString IN OUT VARCHAR2,Delimiter IN OUT VARCHAR2,
DOCUMENTO   VARCHAR2,TOTAL  VARCHAR2,IDENTIDAD  VARCHAR2) AS
   Item    VARCHAR2(8000);
      ItemList       VARCHAR2(8000);
       DelimIndex     INT;
   BEGIN
     ---INICIO IF 1
     IF Delimiter = ' ' THEN
             Delimiter := ',';
             InputString := REPLACE(InputString, ' ', Delimiter);
      END IF;
      --FIN IF1
      
      
      ---INICIO IF  2
      IF (Delimiter IS NULL OR Delimiter = '') THEN
         Delimiter := ',';


       ItemList := InputString;
       DelimIndex := INSTR(Delimiter, ItemList, 0);
      
      ----INICIO WHILE
      WHILE (DelimIndex != 0) LOOP
             Item := SUBSTR(ItemList, 0, DelimIndex);
            
            ---INICIO IF WHILE
            IF Item LIKE '%@%' THEN
                INSERT INTO PAZKO.APROBACION_DETALLE
               (FECHA,IDENTIDAD,APROBACION,ESTADO,IDAPROBACION,APROBADOR,TOTAL)
               VALUES(sysdate,IDENTIDAD,DOCUMENTO,'Pendiente',sys_guid(),Item,TOTAL);
            END IF;   
            ---FIN IF WHILE
           
             ItemList := SUBSTR(ItemList, DelimIndex+1, LENGTH(ItemList)-DelimIndex);
             DelimIndex := INSTR(Delimiter, ItemList, 0);
      END  LOOP;
      ----FIN WHILE

---INICIO IF 3
      IF (Item IS NOT NULL) THEN--al menos un delimitador fue encontrado
      
             Item := ItemList;
            --INICIO IF 5
            IF Item LIKE '%@%' THEN
                INSERT INTO PAZKO.APROBACION_DETALLE
               (FECHA,IDENTIDAD,APROBACION,ESTADO,IDAPROBACION,APROBADOR,TOTAL)
               VALUES(sysdate,IDENTIDAD,DOCUMENTO,'Pendiente',sys_guid(),Item,TOTAL);
            END IF;
            --FIN IF 5
      -- no se encontraron delimitadores
      ELSE 
      ----INICIO IF 6
      IF Item LIKE '%@%' THEN
                INSERT INTO PAZKO.APROBACION_DETALLE
               (FECHA,IDENTIDAD,APROBACION,ESTADO,IDAPROBACION,APROBADOR,TOTAL)
               VALUES(sysdate,IDENTIDAD,DOCUMENTO,'Pendiente',sys_guid(),Item,TOTAL);
     END IF;
     --FIN IF 6
     END IF;
     --FIN IF 3

    END IF;
    ---FIN IF 2
    COMMIT;
   END;
/
```

Pero intento llamarlo de esta forma en sql developer:

```
EXEC PAZKO.SplitAprobadores('FF.FF.HH','.','dsv','hjjhh','jhjhhj');
```

Y me arroja este error:

Error starting at line : 4 in command -
BEGIN PAZKO.SplitAprobadores('FF.FF.HH','.','dsv','hjjhh','jhjhhj'); END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 16:
PLS-00363: expression 'TO_CHAR' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 1, column 40:
PLS-00363: expression 'TO_CHAR' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 1, column 268:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Supongo que tendrá que ver con algo de los parámetros IN OUT ?????